# Consuming SOAP Service with WCF - need to encrypt header

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm writing a .NET 4.5 MVC application and have added a Service Reference.  I'm attempting to consume a Java web service where the request needs to be as follows:

```
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-DC1CFFE24489AA1D8D1384341997399115" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
              <ds:X509Data>
                 <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName />
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber />
                 </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
              </ds:X509Data>
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
           <xenc:CipherValue />
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
           <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-345"/>
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
     </xenc:EncryptedKey>
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-344">
        <wsu:Created>2013-11-13T11:26:37.398Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2014-11-13T11:31:37.398Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-343">
        <wsse:Username />
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-345" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
           <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
           <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                 <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-DC1CFFE24489AA1D8D1384341997399115"/>
              </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
           </ds:KeyInfo>
           <xenc:CipherData>
              <xenc:CipherValue />
           </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

This service also uses an X.509 certificate for the transport security over HTTPS.  I'm able to get it to connect to the service and am sending the user name and password both in plain text (in the usernametoken element.)  Is there a way to adjust the endpoint configuration to encrypt the password in the request?

My current configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="XXX.COM"
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="Root"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                  establishSecurityContext="true"
                  algorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://secure.com/java/service"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior"
        contract="NS.WCF.PPPortType" name="PPPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: there is no way to do it with vanilla WCF, sorry. maybe the service will be ok with you encrypting the whole username header.

Comment: Eh I think you're unfortunately right.  I was able to encrypt the entire body and header of the SOAP message with WCF, however to get it to generate the header according to these specs, I had to create a .NET 2.0 Web Reference while mixing in some WSE 3.0 to finish the details.